# Is there a way to import a bunch of JSON files into Excel

Tags: json, excel, postman

I have about a hundred JSON files of data that I would like to be able to manipulate in Excel. The reason why there are so many files is that the API I pulled from limits responses to 50 items per request, so I chained 100 requests together in Postman and each request generated its own file.

The layout of each file is as follows:

```
{
  "href": "dsjdsjds.com",
  "total": 4293,
  "next": "sdsadsads.com",
  "prev": "dsjdjsdj.com",
  "limit": 50,
  "offset": 50,
  "itemSummaries": [...]
}
```

Pretty much all of the data that I want lies inside the `itemSummaries` class.

I'm pretty new to this and not sure if the optimal way would be to use a Python script, or if there was a way to use VBA or something. I was thinking that I'd need to combine all of the data into a single file first, but I don't know how to do that either. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Whenever someone solves you problem in an answer, you are supposed to **both** click the check mark **and** upvote. The answerer might even thank you by upvoting your question. - Who knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I did for similar situation where I had to import multiple JSON files, all with same structure.

- Use Get & Transform in Data Ribbon to import the JSON file as text.
  The Power Query will recognize this as JSON. Edit the result in Power
  Query window and expand/transform the imported data until you can
  show in tabular form.
- You can then convert these manual sequence of
  steps into Custom Function. See here for details -
  https://www.poweredsolutions.co/2019/02/19/parameters-and-functions-in-power-bi-power-query-custom-functions/
- Go back to Excel and this time instead of importing the JSON file, import the folder where all these JSON are available and apply your custom function on the individual JSON files to produce a consolidated table.

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly. Discover new things with Excel every day.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article.
[Import from JSON](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-a-folder-with-multiple-files-power-query-94b8023c-2e66-4f6b-8c78-6a00041c90e4#bkmk_commands)

Select Data > Get Data > From File > From Folder. The Browse dialog box appears.

Locate the folder containing the files you want to combine.

```
Note    The message “No items match your search” means Power Query has found a folder and it’s displayed in the Folder name box. The files you want to combine are still in the folder, but just not visible.
```

A list of the files in the folder appears in the  dialog box. Verify that all the files you want are listed.

Select one of the commands at the bottom of the dialog box, for example  Combine > Combine & Transform. There are additional commands discussed in the section About all those commands.

```
The Power Query Editor appears.
```

The Value column is a structured List column. Select the Expand   icon, and then select Expand to New rows.

The Value column is now a structured Record column. Select the Expand   icon. A drop-down dialog box appears.

Keep all the columns selected. You may want to clear the Use original column name as a prefix check box. Select OK.

Select all the columns that contain data values. Select Home, the arrow next to Remove Columns, and then select Remove Other Columns.

Select Home > Close & Load.

Result

Power Query automatically creates a query to consolidate the data from each file into a worksheet. The query steps and columns created depend on which command you choose. For more information, see the section, About all those queries.

Comment: Did you test your answer?